# How to get the count of an object in an arraylist at posiition [0]

Tags: c#, arraylist

I have an arraylist that contains objects and other arraylists

if the arraylist object at position 0 has a count of 0 how would i get that count?  i do not want to use a foreach because i need the loop to jump to a different section if the object count is 0

arraylist is something like
<object, arraylist>

and inside each object there are more items such as strings, objects and arraylists-- that goes the same for the arraylists

No i did not create these arraylists-- they come from a 3rd party api which is my bane.

so the initial arraylist will always have a count of one
and inside that arraylist there is <object,arraylist>
if object[0] has a count of 0 i need to exit the loop

so far ive tried

```
  if (arr != null)// && Int32.Parse(((string[])arr[0])[1]) !=0)<--does not like the commented out section
                            {
                                foreach (ArrayList obj in arr)//uses an array inside a dictionary which has more dictionaries in it  <--- if this initial obj.count in the arr is 0 i need to exit
                                {
                                    foreach (Dictionary<string, object> yy in obj)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] rather than just "arraylist is something like" - *showing* code is much better than *describing* code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description, it seems like you have a nested structure of ArrayLists and dictionaries, and you want to exit the loop if the count of the ArrayList at position 0 of the outer ArrayList is 0. You can achieve this in C# using a combination of conditions and break statements. Here's how you can do it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ArrayList outerArrayList = new ArrayList();
        // Populate outerArrayList with your data

        // Check if outerArrayList is not null and has at least one element
        if (outerArrayList != null && outerArrayList.Count > 0)
        {
            // Get the ArrayList at position 0
            ArrayList innerArrayList = outerArrayList[0] as ArrayList;

            // Check if innerArrayList is not null and has a count of 0
            if (innerArrayList != null && innerArrayList.Count == 0)
            {
                // Exit the loop or perform your desired action
                Console.WriteLine("Inner ArrayList count is 0. Exiting the loop.");
            }
            else
            {
                // Iterate over innerArrayList or perform your desired action
                foreach (var item in innerArrayList)
                {
                    // Your logic here
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Handle the case when outerArrayList is empty
            Console.WriteLine("Outer ArrayList is empty.");
        }
    }
}
```